# CUSTOM checkbox / radio buttons without using ID and FOR and using angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to build checkboxes and radiobuttons with a custom image or svg or font instead of the browser's default. It has to work without an input ID / label FOR.  Also I want to do it without jquery dom manipulation. I use Angular.js in my entire application ,so that if there is no pure CSS solution, i need a custom directive.

my target browsers: IE9+ , firefox , chrome desktop/mobile, safari for iphone/ipad.

So far I've been using this pure CSS solution :
http://www.thecssninja.com/css/custom-inputs-using-css
So when clicking on the LABEL, the checkbox/radio input is checked/unchecked.

worked great for a while but the creation of dinamic IDs and FORs to make it work is A PAIN !!
The general solution for checking the input when clicking on the label without using ID/FOR is this structure:

```
<label class="customCheckRadio">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    Check me!!!
</label>
```

[theCssNinja](http://www.thecssninja.com) said about pure CSS solution: "This technique would be impossible without the correct markup order and the ability to create the association between the label and the input. You would have to use JavaScript to solve it."

Does anyone have any solution for this ?...and maybe we can generalize it for everyone once and for all.

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox can be customized without using the Labels. Following is the approach:
1. Hide the checkbox by setting height and width to 0.
2. Use padding to set the height for checkbox container. This gives a div like appearance to checkbox. where actual checkbox is not visible but only its backgroud is visible.
3. Use different propoerties to set the style for checkbox container.

An example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/cysCx/39/

Catch: 
This is not supported in all browsers. (Worked fine on IE9)

CSS:

```
label {  
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align:bottom;
        margin-right: 15px;  

    }  

    input[type=checkbox],
    input[type=radio] {  
        content:"No";
        display: inline-block;
        cursor:pointer;
        padding:10px;
        height:0px;
        width:0px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        background:red;
        vertical-align:bottom;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);

    } 

    input[type=checkbox]:checked,
    input[type=radio]:checked {
        content:"Yes";
        background-color: green;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
        border: 1px solid white;
        /*content: "\2022";
        color: #f3f3f3;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 18px;*/
    }

    input[type=checkbox]:disabled,
    input[type=radio]:disabled {
        background-color: grey;
        box-shadow:none;
        cursor:auto;

    }
```

Comment: The question title asks for a solution without using id and your solution is based on id...

Answer (score 0):

This Might Be Helpful.. Checkout this without using ID and FOR.

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

label i:before {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 3px;
  top: 1px;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  content: "✔";
  color: #333;
}

label input:checked + i:before {
  content: "X";
  color: #ffa500;  
}

label input[disabled] + i:before {
  opacity: .25;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" />Check me
  <i></i>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works without ID's and works in all morder browsers, if you have any issues let me know

```
<body>

 <style>

            .label-wrapper{
            margin-left: 10px;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        .label-wrapper input{
            display: none
        }
        .style-label
        {
            background: green;
            width: 15px;
            height: 15px;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 2px solid grey;
            border-radius: 50%;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .checkboxin:checked + .style-label{
            background: red;
        }


 </style>



<label class="label-wrapper">

    <input type="radio" class="checkboxin" name="radioComponent">

    <span class="style-label"></span>

</label>

    <label class="label-wrapper">

    <input type="radio" class="checkboxin" name="radioComponent">

    <span class="style-label"></span>

</label>

    <label class="label-wrapper">

    <input type="radio" class="checkboxin" name="radioComponent">

    <span class="style-label"></span>

</label>

</body>
```